# Session variable in navigateurl of hyperlink on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, session, hyperlink, navigation, session-variables

I want add one more parameter i.e session["emp_no"] varible in NavigateUrl
How can i achieve this please help

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lblJovid" runat="server" Class="link" NavigateUrl= '<%# Eval("pid", "frm_IAF.aspx?id={0}") %>'  Text='<%# Bind("pid") %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Format` for this:

```
NavigateUrl= '<%# string.Format("frm_IAF.aspx?id={0}&param2={1}", Eval("pid"), Session["emp_no"]) %>'
```